# How can I enable a fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

*Normal disclaimer that I'm a terrible web developer.*

I was lead to believe that, with a `<fieldset disabled id="homeFieldset">...</fieldset>`, I could enable its controls with `$("homeFieldset").disabled = false`, but alas...nothing. Also, I'm testing this in Chrome, where it should work. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ggrxx4hm/1/

FWIW, debugging shows me that `$("#homeFieldset").disabled` is undefined. However, if I do `$("#homeFieldset")[0].disabled = false`, it works. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7edje5vk/

Edited selector in second paragraph.

Edit again: But why doesn't `.disabled = false` work?

Answer to that via @mplungjan in the comments below: "jQuery objects do not have a disabled attribute. DOM objects do. `$("#homeFieldset").disabled=false` is not valid jQuery, `document.getElementById("homeFieldset").disabled=false;` is valid DOM manipulation"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: jQuery objects do not have a disabled attribute. DOM objects do. `$("#homeFieldset").disabled=false` is not valid jQuery, `document.getElementById("homeFieldset").disabled=false;` is valid DOM manipulation

Comment: thank you mplungjan, I don't separate those ideas in my mind. but now I will.

Comment: It is confusing. `document.getElementById("fieldID").value` vs `$("#fieldID").val()` is another one - PS `$("#homeFieldset")[0].disabled = false` is the jQuery version of  `document.getElementById("homeFieldset").disabled=false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggrxx4hm/2/)

`$("#homeFieldset").prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: LOL!!! that is awesome!

Comment: I swear to god I tried that and it didn't work. Brb tossing my pc out

Answer (score 4):

It will work in any of these ways.

```
$("#homeFieldset")[0].disabled = false; // accessing the DOM object
OR 
$("#homeFieldset").attr('disabled',false); // using the jQuery attr
```

Your code doesnt work since you have to tell jquery to change Attribute.

Comment: missing the # in the selector

Comment: Thanks, edited @gavgrif

Comment: ^^^what he said, edit your answer, +1

Comment: Note that as of Jquery 1.6, the `prop()` method should be used to set `disabled` instead of using the `.attr()` method. [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1):

for enable

```
$("#homeFieldset").prop('disabled', false);
```

and for disable

```
$("#homeFieldset").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Use `$("#homeFieldset")` - note the `#` in the selector.

Read more on jQuery selectors here: [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)